# socket.io id is not conform and don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Whene I get id of socket (socket.id) he return "/privateroom#cL-qy2G6gVfwUY_ZAAAH" the socket is in "/privateroom" namespace. but whene I want to send a message to socket with id that doesn't work. in documentation the id is just "cL-qy2G6gVfwUY_ZAAAH" i don't understand why that is different.
my socket version is ^2.3.0

Comment: I have found answer:     namespace.to(id).emit()